# $stateChangeStart is not firing in logout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have defined `Loginctrl` in index page and called it in `login.html`. Once the user logged in ,he can view a menu where user can navigate to every module (based on the click, `ctrler` will be changed as mentioned in router). In each module I have called 
**$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)** to track whether user have made any changes.

This event is firing properly in module navigation, but if i click the logout icon (logout method is in `loginctrl`),logout method is fired first and then this event gets fired.

Why this event is not firing even the state gets changed?

Comment: you may need to listen on $locationChangeStart event, but you can't get state params from that.

Comment: I am using State.go , so i cannot listen to $locationChangeStart.

Comment: Maybe your logout button is above the scope where you are listening `$stateChangeStart`. Did you try `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ...)` ?

Comment: yes  i used , it is not firing first.only logoutMethod is getting fired

Comment: Actually in my html i am calling the loginctrl in first div , inside same div ,I have <ul>  for modules navigation  and Logout method.. is it because of that Statechange event not firing